# Find axis intercept using ggplot

Tags: r, regression, ggplot2

I'm currently doing an assignment using R about the photoelectric effect - for those who don't know, the y-axis intercept of the straight line created by the data is the work function ($\phi$) of the metal the experiment was performed on. I've managed to plot a linear regression line that tracks back to 0 on the x-axis but how can I find this value?

My only solution is to draw a horizontal line and fit it visually but that's an awful solution and is likely to have a huge error. I've attached an image of the plot in case that helps.

[image: Current plot - just to display problem]

Also as an aside - if anyone knows how to make the axes such that the intercept point starts at the bottom left hand corner ie no indents as there are now, that would be incredible!

Thanks so much, and please do excuse any formatting trespasses - it's my first post and I've tried my best!

Answer (score 2):

If you were to perform this as a linear regression, in R, you would receive the intercept term (the point at which the line touches the y-axis, which is equivalent to the value of y when the x-variable is 0). If you are using the ggplot2 package to graph the least squares line through the data points, `ggplot` can use a `stat_smooth(method = "lm")`, to help draw the line.

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data=d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()  
p + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x)
```

You're looking for the intercept value in the summary output of m.

```
m <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(m)
```

Hopefully this helps, if not, please clarify and glad to try to assist.

Edit:

Reference ggplot, as there are xlim and ylim variables as needed.